# Injecting a SessionScope bean in Controller not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, session-state, spring-bean

I am having trouble setting an attribute value ie. `shortname` to a SessionScope bean in Spring Boot.

Here is my class:

```
    import java.util.Map;

    public class LdapUser {
        private String shortname = "";
        private Map<String,String> token = null;
        private String id = "";
    
    public LdapUser() {
           
        }
    
        public String getshortname() {
            return shortname;
        }
    
        public void setshortname(String shortname) {
            this.shortname = shortname;
        }
... remaining geters and setters
```

My Bean definition is here:

```
import xxx.controllers.SwitchController;
import xxx.isim.LdapUser;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@Configuration
public class RestTemplateClient {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SwitchController.class);

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public LdapUser sessionScopedLdapUser() {
        logger.info("LdapUser bean instance created");
        return new LdapUser();
    }
}
```

I am using the Bean in a Controller:

```
import xxx.errors.IsimConnectionException;
import xxx.isim.IsimConnection;
import xxx.isim.LdapUser;
import xxx.services.IsimRestApiService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.security.Principal;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @Autowired
    IsimRestApiService isimConn;

    @Resource(name = "sessionScopedLdapUser")
    LdapUser sessionScopedLdapUser;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Principal principal) throws IsimConnectionException {
        Authentication authentication = (Authentication) principal;

        /

        if ((authentication.getPrincipal() != null) && (authentication.isAuthenticated())) {
            // set the shortname for the session
            String shortname = (String)authentication.getPrincipal();
            sessionScopedLdapUser.setshortname(shortname); //<-----
```

My Bean's value for `shortname` remains null after the line with the arrow even though I correctly get the `shortname` String value and that one is not null. Can you please point me out what am I doing wrong when setting the bean attribute values. I followed the example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes#2-session-scope) for SessionScope Beans

**Update:**
I also tried to use autowired instead of @Resource(name = "sessionScopedLdapUser") but the value still remains null after executing `sessionScopedLdapUser.setshortname(shortname);`

```
 @Autowired
 LdapUser sessionScopedLdapUser
```

Also in the log I can see the LdapUser bean instance is created three times. How is that possible?

```
2021-09-21 10:55:55,469 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-4] xxx.config.RestTemplateClient: LdapUser bean instance created
2021-09-21 10:57:05,247 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-4] xxx.config.RestTemplateClient: LdapUser bean instance created
2021-09-21 10:58:08,401 INFO  [http-nio-8080-exec-4] xxx.config.RestTemplateClient: LdapUser bean instance created
```

The ideas is to have one bean per HTTP session. I am really confused and would appreciate some hints. I was reading this [article](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/injecting-singleton-with-prototype-bean.html) and maybe that is because I am trying to inject a Session Scope bean to a Singletone bean.

My file structure is:

```
xxx
---auth
---config
   --- RestRemplateClient
---controllers
   --- HomeController
---errors
---isim
   --- LdapUser
---services
Mainapp
```

Comment: Can you try adding @SessionAttributes(types = { LdapUser .class})  at Controller level in your HomeController ?

Comment: `@SessionAttributes` is for something totally different. Please include the import statements in your code, as I wonder **which** `@SessionScope` annotation you are using. Using `@Resource` or `@Autowired` doesn't change a thing. One thing I wonder when is it `null`? How do you check this? Is it `null` in your debugger, or `null` somewhere else?

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum I apologise, I haven't originally seen your questions. I included the import statements in my original question. I check the  value of the bean field `shortname` in the debugger. I tried both @SessionScope and @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)

Comment: If you check in the debugger, the field will appear `null` because you are looking at the proxy and not the real object in the session. So basically your mind is playing tricks on you. If you check the debugger you will see that the type is actually something like `LdapUser$EnchangedBySpring_Cgling$12343`, this will have several callbacks etc. associated and if you dig deeper you will find the actual session scoped instance. But for now you are looking at the proxy **not** the actual object.

Comment: Thanks so much @M. Deinum  Programmatically it appears it works correctly. As you pointed out, the debugger value for the field is from the proxy. It took me 2 days to come to terms with this :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @M. Deinum I was able to figure it out. I was looking at the field value in the debugger and that one was always null since I was looking the proxy and not the real object.

Here is the code that injects a **session scoped bean** in the @Controller class. It also works correctly and in the same way in the @Service class.

```
public class LdapUser {
    private String shortname = "";
    private Map<String,String> token = new HashMap<>();
    private String id = "";

    public LdapUser() {
        this.shortname = shortname;
        this.token = token;
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getshortname() {
        return shortname;
    }

    public void setshortname(String shortname) {
        this.shortname = shortname;
    }
 ... other getters and setters
```

My bean configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateClient {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SwitchController.class);

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}

@Bean
@SessionScope
public LdapUser sessionScopedLdapUser() {
    logger.info("LdapUser bean instance created at "+ LocalDateTime.now());
    return new LdapUser();
}
```

}

My controller class:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

@Autowired
IsimRestApiService isimConn;

@Autowired
LdapUser sessionScopedLdapUser;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Principal principal) throws IsimConnectionException {
    Authentication authentication = (Authentication) principal;

    //System.out.println("******* USER IS " + authentication.getPrincipal());

    if ((authentication.getPrincipal() != null) && (authentication.isAuthenticated())) {
        // set the shortname for the session
        String shortname = (String)authentication.getPrincipal();

        sessionScopedLdapUser.setshortname(shortname);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can specify your configurations as below:-

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class LdapUser {

    private String shortName = "LdapUser Session Scope";
// other properties
    
    public LdapUser() {
        System.out.println("LdapUser SessionScope Constructor Called at "+LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    public void setShortName(String shortName) {
        this.shortName = shortName;
    }
}
```

In configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateClient {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SwitchController.class);

    @Autowired
    private LdapUser ldapUser;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    public void setLdapUser(LdapUser ldapUser) {
    this.ldapUser = ldapUser;
    }

    public LdapUser getLdapUser() {
    return ldapUser;
    }
}
```

and into your controller:-

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
// Other Codes

@Autowired
private RestTemplateClient restTemplateClient;

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @Autowired
    IsimRestApiService isimConn;

@RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(Principal principal) throws IsimConnectionException {
        Authentication authentication = (Authentication) principal;

        /

        if ((authentication.getPrincipal() != null) && (authentication.isAuthenticated())) {
            // set the shortname for the session
            String shortname = (String)authentication.getPrincipal();
restTemplateClient.getLdapUser().setShortName("LdapUser Session Scope Updated");
// .... Other codes
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @N K Shukla Beside the shortname I have two other values I need to store per session namely `private Map<String,String> token` and  `private String id` and that is the reason I used a SessionScope bean.

Comment: @Anuska Please try with the updated solutions approach.

Comment: The result should be the same, if this works there is something else wrong with his code. Adding an additional layer isn't the solution.

Comment: Isn't it proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS is playing a role ? It defines how Spring will proxy your bean. In this case, it will proxy by retaining the target class. @M.Deinum

Comment: `@SessionScope` is shorthand for that and in this case will automatically use a class proxy because there is no interface.

Comment: Thanks @N K Shukla but I am still not able to set values in the bean. They remain null.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please suggest what am I doing wrong configuring the bean.

Comment: I asked some question, without answering those this is impossible to answer.